# Recognize hand written digits using Tesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, text-recognition, handwriting-recognition

I have fetched this roll number section from the OMR sheet
[image: Roo Number Field]

Now, my main task is to recognize handwritten digits and return the roll number value as text in Python. I tried using pytesseract. But, it is not giving proper results.

Here is my sample code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

def recognize_digit(image):
    ## Preprocess the image for OCR
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=0.9, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
    equalized = clahe.apply(gray)
    threshold = cv2.threshold(equalized, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(threshold, h=0)
    # Remove horizontal
    horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (24,1))
    detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)
        cv2.drawContours(denoised, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
        cv2.drawContours(threshold, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
    
    # Remove vertical
    vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,25))
    detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)
        cv2.drawContours(denoised, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
        cv2.drawContours(threshold, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
    
    cv2.imshow('X', denoised)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Apply OCR using Tesseract
    config = "--psm 7 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789"
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(denoised, config=config)

    return text.strip()

# Read the image
image_path = 'aligned_image.jpeg'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Define the region of interest (coordinates of the desired region)
x, y, w, h = 4, 4, 800, 100

# Crop the image to the defined region
roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# Recognize the handwritten digit within the cropped region
recognized_digit = recognize_digit(roi)

# Print the recognized digit
print("Recognized digit:", recognized_digit)
```

How can get proper solution for this.

Comment: *But, it is not giving proper results* What did you expect? What is it giving? Be specific!

Comment: I want proper output like- 0702161
But I am getting 072161 as result

Comment: Is it detecting the contour for "0"? If not, what image fails in your processing?  Have you looked at your threshold image for the "0"? Have you looked at your denoised image for the "0". Have you looked at your morphology cleaned image for the "0"? What debugging have you done?

Comment: If you are not limited to using pytesseract, how about training a simple yolov5/yolov8 model to recognize digits and then merge the outputs. This should give a significant increase in accuracy and you will be able to control the output (which you can't in pytesseract).

Answer (score 1):

Pytesseract doesn't work quite well for hand written data, specially when there's variation. While you can improve the results by applying different image processing techniques, like otsu thresholding to remove the noise, the resize the image such that the details are visible and then sharpen the image but these improvements wouldn't be much.

If you want better results with a free tool, I'd advice using `PaddleOCR` which performs significantly better than `Pytesseract` when it comes to detection accuracy.

Here's a sample code to use their pretrained weights to run detections:

```py
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR,draw_ocr
# Paddleocr supports Chinese, English, French, German, Korean and Japanese.
# You can set the parameter `lang` as `ch`, `en`, `fr`, `german`, `korean`, `japan`
# to switch the language model in order.
ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en') # need to run only once to download and load model into memory
img_path = './imgs_en/img_12.jpg'
result = ocr.ocr(img_path, cls=True)
for idx in range(len(result)):
    res = result[idx]
    for line in res:
        print(line)


# draw result
from PIL import Image
result = result[0]
image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
boxes = [line[0] for line in result]
txts = [line[1][0] for line in result]
scores = [line[1][1] for line in result]
im_show = draw_ocr(image, boxes, txts, scores, font_path='./fonts/simfang.ttf')
im_show = Image.fromarray(im_show)
im_show.save('result.jpg')
```

For further details follow their official documentation which provides information for finetuning, inferencing and best practices: https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR